# JQuery Mobile / Phonegap on android - all text shows in caps

Tags: android, jquery, cordova

I am building a phonegap (2.3.0) + jQuery Mobile (1.2) App.

All works reasonably well, but I am not able to get any text to show in mixed upper/lower case letters-

Example:

```
<p>This is my stuff:</p>
```

shows up:
THIS IS MY STUFF:

I tried adding style="font-variant: normal"

```
<p style="font-variant:normal">This is my stuff:</p>
```

but I still get
THIS IS MY STUFF:

I tried to change the stylesheet on top (all css load before):

```
<style>
        body  * {
                font-variant: normal !important;
            }
</style>
```

still everything is upper case.

I verified that the font I use is a mixed upper/lower case font and not an all Caps-Font.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Try text-transform property:

```
text-transform: none;
```

Comment: This is buddy brilliant! Works! Thanks a lot!

Comment: I am using phonegap 3.0.0 and NO jquery mobile and had the same issue so jquery mobile has nothing to do with it. This solved it.

Answer (score 14):

Phonegap defines in `index.css`:

```
body {
 ...  
 text-transform:uppercase;  
 ...
}
```

Do not know why, just comment it out.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with with phonegap 3.3 jquery 1.4.1 the solution was to chance the index.css 
body {
 ...
 text-transform:uppercase;
 ...
}
to
body {
 ...
 text-transform:none;
 ...
}

Comment: you should try to format your answer so that the code is easier to read.